# VBA - export to .csv without blank lines at the bottom

Tags: vba, csv

I am using the below to export a whole worksheet to csv. This csv file is then sent via SFTP. However, it keeps creating csv files with numerous empty lines at the bottom which are causing issues on the receiving end. How do I ensure the csv does not have these empty lines?

```
Sub ExportCSVTIS()

'Export TISUpload tab as CSV

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TISUpload")     'Sheet to export as CSV
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add

shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                       
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\AutoUploads\Upload_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_hhmm") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions to find the last nonempty cell. This is a quick and simple solution:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Variant
Dim MaxRow As Long
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each c In r
    If LenB(Trim(c)) > 0 Then
        If c.Row > MaxRow Then MaxRow = c.Row
    End If
Next

r.Resize(MaxRow).Copy Destination:=wbkExport.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thank you!! Perfect response.